# Does the Hadamard product of two vectors have a geometric interpretation?

Tags: linear-algebra, hadamard-product, geometric-interpretation

Pointwise multiplication (or element-wise) is also known as the Hadamard product. Is there a geometric interpretation similar to addition or subtraction in vector spaces?

Comment: This question is exactly what I'm looking for, but unfortunately remains unanswered even after nearly 6 years. :(

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754366/geometric-interpretation-of-element-wise-vector-multiplication

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337671/why-isnt-intuitive-vector-multiplication-useful and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185888/why-dont-we-define-vector-multiplication-component-wise and https://medium.com/linear-algebra/part-14-dot-and-hadamard-product-b7e0723b9133 and https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/97r5y7/motivation_for_hadamard_product/

Comment: And https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82272966.pdf