# The "extended" dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

The standard dot product of two vectors $\vec{u},\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is given by:

$ \vec{u}\cdot \vec{v} = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i$

Assuming now that I have $m$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, does the following product have a name, and does it have any interesting properties:

$P = \sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^m v_{j,i}$

In other words, it's the extension to the dot product, which is defined as the sum of element-wise products of all vectors.

Comment: Isn't it just $v_1 \cdot v_2 \cdots v_m$?

Comment: @WhatsUp $v_1 \cdot v_2$ is a number, how do you take the dot product of a number and a vector?

Comment: I don't think so, for the reason mentioned by @Najib Idrissi

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. This is an $m$-linear map from $(\mathbb{R}^n)^m$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/185888/8157) is related. You can define whatever operation on vectors you want, but if it is not "geometric" (in the sense that it does not depend on the choice of coordinates) then it will probably be of marginal use.

Comment: What exactly does $v_{I,j}$ mean here

Comment: It seems that it is, in fact, a multilinear map.  I'm interested in questions like: under what conditions is it zero for non-zero vectors $\vec{v}_j$?  I'm not entirely sure if there is a nice answer, though

Comment: @Dan, it is the $i^{th}$ entry of vector $j$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I don't think the usual dot product is "geometric" in your sense. Neither do I think it is of marginal use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: it is a multilinear map.  So yes it has a name, and yes it has interesting properties.  The properties are the subject of study of multi-linear algebra, so are too vast to mention here.

Comment: The question is "does the following product have a name, and does it have any interesting properties". So I think the answer should be one of the four: "yes, yes", "yes, no", "no, yes", "no, no".

Comment: Edited and fixed :-)

Comment: Well ... I was just kidding ... but agree that it's too vast to talk about "interesting properties" here.